# OpenIddict - Device Code Flow & Refresh Tokens

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, openiddict

I cant seem to have a refresh token (OpenIddict.Core 3.1.1) in the response of `/connect/token` when using device code flow.

This is my server configuration :

```
// OpenIddict
builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options =>
        options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
            .UseDbContext<AnimaCareContext>())
    .AddServer(options =>
    {
        options.SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
            .SetLogoutEndpointUris("/connect/logout")
            .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
            .SetDeviceEndpointUris("/connect/device")
            .SetVerificationEndpointUris("/connect/verify")
            .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo");

        options.RegisterClaims(Permission.ClaimType);

        options.RegisterScopes(OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Email, OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Profile,
            OpenIddictConstants.Scopes.Roles);

        options.AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow()
            .AllowDeviceCodeFlow()
            .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
        options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromHours(12));//Extend session timeout to 12 hours
        options.SetRefreshTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(5));

        options.AddDevelopmentEncryptionCertificate()
            .AddDevelopmentSigningCertificate();

        options.UseAspNetCore()
            .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
            .EnableLogoutEndpointPassthrough()
            .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
            .EnableVerificationEndpointPassthrough()
            .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough()
            .EnableStatusCodePagesIntegration()
            .DisableTransportSecurityRequirement();
    })
    .AddValidation(options =>
    {
        options.UseLocalServer();
        options.UseAspNetCore();
    });
```

And the `AuthorizationController` :

```
    [HttpPost("~/connect/token"), Produces("application/json")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Exchange()
    {
        var request = HttpContext.GetOpenIddictServerRequest() ??
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The OpenID Connect request cannot be retrieved.");

        if (request.IsDeviceCodeGrantType() || request.IsAuthorizationCodeGrantType() || request.IsRefreshTokenGrantType())
        {
            var result = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            var principal =
              (await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme))
              .Principal;

            var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(result.Principal.GetClaim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Subject));
            if (user is null)
            {
                return Forbid(
                    authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    properties: new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = OpenIddictConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                        [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "The token is no longer valid."
                    }));
            }

            if (!await _signInManager.CanSignInAsync(user))
            {
                return Forbid(
                    authenticationSchemes: OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                    properties: new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
                    {
                        [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.Error] = OpenIddictConstants.Errors.InvalidGrant,
                        [OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreConstants.Properties.ErrorDescription] = "The user is no longer allowed to sign in."
                    }));
            }
            foreach (var claim in principal.Claims)
            {
                claim.SetDestinations(GetDestinations(claim, principal));
            }

            return SignIn(principal, OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }

        throw new InvalidOperationException("The specified grant type is not supported.");
    }

    private IEnumerable<string> GetDestinations(Claim claim, ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        switch (claim.Type)
        {
            case OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Name:
                yield return OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken;

                if (principal.HasScope(OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Profile))
                    yield return OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken;

                yield break;

            case OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Email:
                yield return OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken;

                if (principal.HasScope(OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Email))
                    yield return OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken;

                yield break;

            case OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Role:
                yield return OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken;

                if (principal.HasScope(OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Roles))
                    yield return OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken;

                yield break;

            case Permission.ClaimType:
                yield return OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken;

                if (principal.HasScope(OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.Scopes.Roles))
                    yield return OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.IdentityToken;

                yield break;

            case "AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp": yield break;

            default:
                yield return OpenIddictConstants.Destinations.AccessToken;
                yield break;
        }
    }
```

And after validation of the device code, only the access token is returned.
[image: Token Response]

I've compared my code with one of the samples and found almost the same configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, the important part there is having the refresh token flow enabled on the server by calling `AllowRefreshTokenFlow`.

Additionally, make sure that the client application being used has a permission for the refresh token grant type (`OpenIddictConstants.Permissions.GrantTypes.RefreshToken`), and when requesting a token, that the scope `offline_access` is passed in the `scope` parameter for the request.